# How to remove this 1940s door hardware from the door?

Tags: doors, hardware, doorknob

I have a set of 1940s-era door hardware that seems to be broken so I'd like to remove it from the door. I have removed the knobs and latch but the cam is too big to fit through the holes on either side of the door:

- side 1:

[image]

- side 2:

[image]

Inside the hole for the latch is this metal piece:

[image]

that connects to the latch which is what is making it too wide to fit through the sides of the door. I cannot see any buttons or ways to detach this piece - any ideas how I can get this hardware out of my door? Thanks!

Comment: Please remove your "update" and copy/paste it into the box labeled "Your Answer". After all, this is a Question & Answer forum, not a general discussion site. In 2 days, the system will allow you to click the check mark showing that this question has an accepted answer and that will make it easier for others to learn from you. You can take the [tour] to learn more.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was able to insert a screwdriver to depress a pin behind this metal piece which after some effort caused it to retract:

[image]

Once it was retracted, I was able to pull it out one of the sides:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The mechanism is installed & removed from the latch side. Once you've removed the knob, the screws on the latch side, and any other pieces that might hold it in, you should be able to pull it out. You may want to use something like a screwdriver for leverage, and it might be useful to run a knife around the edges of the metal plate around the latch to help detach from any surrounding paint.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I was eventually able to figure it out - see the above update - by depressing a small pin that allowed this metal piece to retract.

Comment: @garibaldi: You might want to make that an Answer so folks can up-vote it.